# IOS and Android Developing in Windows

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I am currently developing Android Applications and would like to enter into IOS developing. Many have advised the use of cross platform development tools. I hav searched and found nothing solid. Can anyone suggest a good cross platform deveoping IDE for IOS and Android. Please give suggestions that is sure to work.

Comment: `Good` is depend on each person point of view so it's hard to tell what is good for me is good for you. Choose one and start coding.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. Trust nothing other than xcode and objective c for native iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with these both Cross platforms. these are simple to use.

- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) Titanium for cross platform applications.

Using this you can Create rich native iOS, Android, hybrid, and mobile web apps from a single JavaScript-based SDK

- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Developing with PhoneGap gives you the freedom to create mobile applications for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada and Symbian using the web code you know and love: HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova/PhoneGap works well between iOS and Android but the down side is that you have to use HTML and javascript to implement your application. Native elements such as maps require quite a lot of work although there are many plugins for them. Unfortunately plugins are not standard.

Style sheets and html are good, because they make it relatively easy to scale the application over the huge array of screen sizes.

Window phone has problems with standards and old models are quite slow, but perhaps there is an improvement in WP8.